# 404 Error when calling jQuery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-post

I'm trying to us jquery.post in my rails application. I am getting a 404 (not found) error as a result.

error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/user_versions/create/1/13/ 404 (Not
Found)jquery.js?body=1:9632
jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js?body=1:9177
jQuery.extend.ajaxjquery.js?body=1:9323 jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous
function)apps.js?body=1:53 (anonymous function)jquery.js?body=1:4642
jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js?body=1:4310
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

routes.rb

```
post 'user_versions/create/:user_id/:version_id', to: 'user_versions#create'
```

apps.js.erb

```
$('.download-btn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var build = $(this).data('build');
  var user_id = $('#current_user_id').val();
  console.log(build);
  console.log(user_id);
  var path = "/user_versions/create/" + user_id + "/" + build + "/";
  $.post( path, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

user_versions_controller.rb

```
class UserVersionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = params[:user_id]
    version = params[:version_id]
    UserVersion.find_or_create_by(user: user, version: version)
    render text: "success"
  end
end
```

***UPDATE***

I updated the code to follow @maxd suggestion. The error that I am not getting in the rails view is

POST http://localhost:3000/user_versions/create/1/3 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery.js?body=1:9632 jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js?body=1:9177 jQuery.extend.ajaxjquery.js?body=1:9323 jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function)apps.js?body=1:53 (anonymous function)jquery.js?body=1:4642 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js?body=1:4310 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle

When I call the same in [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) it get a 422 Unprocessable Entity Status

Comment: Does it need the last `/` in the var `path`?

Comment: @jorg I've tried that

Comment: is this proper syntax: `user_versions/#create`? I think it should be: `user_versions#create`. Please post the output of your `rake routes`

Comment: Could you please provide error from console log (or from log/development.log) for HTTP code 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try to remove `/` from `... to: 'user_versions/#create'`

2) Check URL path use `rake routes | grep user_versions`.

Comment: rake routes `POST   /user_versions/create/:user_id/:version_id(.:format) user_versions#create`

Answer (score 1):

path should be '/user_versions/create', and post data put in object, like:

```
var data = {
    user_id: user_id,
    version_id: build
};
$.post( path, data, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```